# iptables with virtual interface

Tags: nat

I have the following interfaces: eth0, eth0:0, and eth1. eth0:0 is virtual and also it faces WAN (interent). eth0 is 192.168.0.0/24 and eth1 is 10.0.0.0/24. How can I enable NAT and make eth0:0 as gateway for both 192.168.0.0/24 and 10.0.0.0/24 networks.

Comment: Do you mean: eth0:0 has a public IP address? Okay, now I'm confused. If eth0 is a *private* network, why do you put a public IP there??

Comment: I have only two interfaces, and I want both for private network.

Comment: can you post the output of `ifconfig`, `ip address show`, and `ip route show`? Feel free to replace any public IP with a generalized one (e.g., 11.22.33.xx)

Comment: @pepoluan I bought and  installed a third NIC, and you gave the right solution in another question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

iptables doesn't support virtual interfaces, so you have to match IP ranges in rules in order to achieve this.